# How to use GeoIP With Nginx On Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: nginx

I want a tutorial to help me in using  GeoIP with Nginx on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [this link](http://www.howtoforge.com/using-geoip-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12.04) for Using GeoIP With Nginx On Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you provide detail on the link here please. See our [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). Thanks!